# React child components from array - issue when moving elements to other indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

[SOLVED]

We're attempting to create a component best described as a "tab view", which renders content dynamically (not from a pre-made component structure) - with buttons. The component itself is completed. However, there is one issue: when the pages' state is re-ordered it's child elements lose their actual state. What I'm trying to describe is similar to when you're re-ordering and moving around tabs in your web browser.
Imagine you're moving one tab to the first position only to find that every input field loses it's content and etc. The page basically resets.

Children elements are always rendered, but every inactive tab is hidden with the exception of the only active tab (CSS display: none;).

```
const addToArray = (item) => {
  setChilds([...childs, item]);
 };

const removeFromArray = (from) => {
  const newChilds = [...childs];
  newChilds.splice(from, 1);
  setChilds(newChilds);
};

const move = (from, to) => {
  const newChilds = [...childs];
  newChilds.splice(from, 1);
  newChilds.splice(to, 0, childs[from]); // most likely cause of bug
  setChilds(newChilds);
};

export const TabSwitch = () => {
  const { path, routes } = useRouter();
  return (
    <div>
      {routes.map((route: IRoute) => {
        return (
          <Route key={route.path} isActive={path === route.path}>
            {route.component}
          </Route>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The code above is what we're using to add, remove and move elements. The code functions properly when adding or removing elements from the array. The issue only occurs when we're moving an element to a different index.

There are two questions to be answered: what is the cause of the bug and how do we solve it?

Comment: It sounds like you might be using index as `key` value when you map the tab components? You'll need to show your render/return for more help.

Comment: Okay, solved by @pilchard 's comment. The problem was the index as key. Thank you!